# im trying to read in bytes and xor them with a stored byte in my program but im a bit lost can anyone help heres my code

Tags: java

Trying get my program to read in bytes and xor them with my stored byte but not seem to work

```
import java.io.*;
public class ByteReadExample {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try
    {
        byte key=1;

        while(((byte)System.in.read())!= key ) {

        System.out.print(key^System.in.read());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

 }
```

Comment: What is the question? Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: "It does not work" doesn't tell us anything. All you told us is what your program does. But you didn't told ur what it's supposed to do. What's your input, your actual output, and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `System.in.read`, it reads another byte. So you need to store the byte read into a variable, so that you can look at it again.